# How does the possible attack on passwords and salts mentioned in PKCS#5 v2.1 work?

Tags: passwords, symmetric, salt

From [PKCS#5](https://pkcs5.grieu.fr/#page=6) v2.1, 4.1 Salt (page 6, emphasis by me), also in [v2.0, RFC 2898](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2898#section-4.1):

> In password-based encryption, the party encrypting a message can
> gain    assurance that these benefits are realized simply by selecting
> a    large and sufficiently random salt when deriving an encryption
> key    from a password. A party generating a message authentication
> code can    gain such assurance in a similar fashion.
>
> The party decrypting a message or verifying a message
> authentication    code, however, cannot be sure that a salt supplied
> by another party    has actually been generated at random. It is
> possible, for instance,    that the salt may have been copied from
> another password-based    operation, in an attempt to exploit
> interactions between multiple    uses of the same key. For instance,
> suppose two legitimate parties    exchange a encrypted message, where
> the encryption key is an 80-bit    key derived from a shared password
> with some salt. **An opponent could    take the salt from that
> encryption and provide it to one of the    parties as though it were
> for a 40-bit key. If the party reveals the    result of decryption
> with the 40-bit key, the opponent may be able to    solve for the
> 40-bit key. In the case that 40-bit key is the first    half of the
> 80-bit key, the opponent can then readily solve for the    remaining
> 40 bits of the 80-bit key.**

The part I don't really understand is where it saids "If the party reveals the result of decryption with the 40-bit key, ..."

Could I get some clarification of this?

Answer (score 5):

This appears to be describing an attack that allows an active attacker to defeat a seemingly-secure protocol.

In the normal setting where no one is attacking them, Alice and Bob share a password $W$; Alice derives a symmetric key $K$ from the password $W$ and encrypts her message with $K$, then sends it to Bob; now Bob can derive the same key (since he knows the password $W$), decrypt, and learn the message.  At least, that's how things work when there is no attacker.  If Alice derives a 80-bit key $K$, and if the password is sufficiently strong, then this scheme might be secure against eavesdroppers.

The part you quote is talking about an active attack that could defeat the security of that arrangement.  Recall that Alice (the sender) encrypted with a 80-bit key $K$ (derived from a password $W$).  In the attack, an active attacker modifies the ciphertext somehow so that the recipient Bob will decrypt it with a 40-bit key $K'$ (derived from the same password $W$).  Suppose the derivation procedure has the property that $K'$ is the first 40 bits of $K$.

When Bob decrypts the ciphertext under $K'$, he will get gibberish (since he is decrypting with a different key than Alice encrypted with).  Suppose that Bob replies to Bob with a complaint that decryption failed, quoting the gibberish he got back.  Now the attacker can learn $K'$. Notice that a 40-bit key $K'$ does not provide adequate security, and in this scenario, the attacker knows both the ciphertext and its decryption under key $K'$; thus, the attacker can use trial decryption to find the key $K'$.

At this point the attacker knows the first 40 bits of the key $K$ that Alice encrypted with.  Thus, by doing exhaustive keysearch (trial decryption) on the remaining unknown 40 bits of $K$, the attacker can recover the full key $K$ and decrypt the message.  In this way the attacker learns the resulting message.

This is a related-parameter/related-key attack, where the attacker desynchronizes the endpoints and causes them to use different, conflicting parameters (e.g., different keys, different key lengths).  In general, a well-designed key exchange scheme should be designed to prevent such attacks.  Without additional context, I'd guess that the part you are quoting is explaining the need to guard against such attacks.